# Create column relative to other values in same column (time since last transaction) Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset has two columns with userid and transaction time. I would like to create a third column that indicates time since last purchase by user. For example:

```
User Id Timestamp
92212   2015-08-20T15:52:53
26123   2015-10-29T14:44:06
92212   2015-07-21T16:21:55
```

The third column would hold something like:

```
1
0
0
```

Where 1 indicates one months since last purchase (Aug vs Jul) and 0 indicates first purchase (or maybe better suited for NaN?).

Essentially, I need to group userids, order transaction times chronologically and calculate distance to the prior chronological time. Also open to any other approach to solving retention since last order by month.

I've packed it into code like this at the moment:

```
def monthSinceLastOrder(transactionArray):
    transactionArray = transactionArray.order()
    monthValues = []
    for transDate in transactionArray:
        monthValues.append(transDate.month)
    distance = [-1]
    for i in monthValues:
        if monthValues[0]==i:
            prior=i
        else:
            distance.append(i-prior)
            prior=i
    return distance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing the Pandas `Split-Apply-Combine` method.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

We can group by the User Id, and then for each group apply a function to evaluate the difference between the rows.

Let's set up the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'User Id': '9272', 'Timestamp': '2015-08-20T15:52:53'},
    {'User Id': '26121', 'Timestamp': '2015-10-29T14:44:06'},
    {'User Id': '9272', 'Timestamp': '2015-07-21T16:21:55'},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
```

Now define a function that will operate on each group, and apply it.

The function sorts by Timestamp, and creates a new `Delta` column for each row, set to the difference between itself and the prior row.  Where there is no prior row (i.e. first purchase), it returns NaT.

```
def x(frame):
    frame.sort('Timestamp', inplace=True)
    frame['Delta'] = frame['Timestamp'] - frame['Timestamp'].shift(1)
    return frame

df.groupby(['User Id'], group_keys=False).apply(x)
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
    Timestamp           User Id Delta
1   2015-10-29 14:44:06 26121   NaT
2   2015-07-21 16:21:55 9272    NaT
0   2015-08-20 15:52:53 9272    29 days 23:30:58
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and review of split-apply-combine.

Answer (score 0):

The way to think about this in terms of a vectorised operation is to use `shift` to offset the timestamp column, and then just use a subtraction (this will be broadcast along the array)

```
df.sort_values(by='Timestamp')\
  .groupby('User')\
  .apply(lambda x: x['Timestamp'] - x['Timestamp'].shift())

User    
26123  1                NaT
92212  2                NaT
       0   29 days 23:30:58
Name: Id, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks for introducing the shift function.